# Error trying to use cmake on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, cmake

I'm trying to run build dlib on Ubuntu 16.04 using cmake. I had it working before but recently ran into a problem so I uninstalled cmake and tried reinstalling. However, whenever I try to use cmake or check the version via:

```
cmake --version
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/cmake", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('cmake==3.13.3', 'console_scripts', 'cmake')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cmake-3.13.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/cmake/__init__.py", line 34, in cmake
    raise SystemExit(_program('cmake', sys.argv[1:]))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cmake-3.13.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/cmake/__init__.py", line 30, in _program
    return subprocess.call([os.path.join(CMAKE_BIN_DIR, name)] + args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 523, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I reinstalled and resourced via:

```
sudo apt-get remove cmake cmake-data
sudo -E add-apt-repository -y ppa:george-edison55/cmake-3.x
sudo -E apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cmake
. ~/.bashrc
```

I then uninstalled, but it wasn't completely removed via:

```
sudo apt-get remove cmake
```

and then reinstalled via:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake
```

Please let me know if any other information is needed.

SOLVED:

Using https://cmake.org/download/ and this [guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_yFPO1ofyF0&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: What if you remove that apt-repository and install via pip ( https://pypi.org/project/cmake/ ) or the cmake installer .sh files ( https://cmake.org/download/ , vector-of-bool has a [guide on using that](https://youtu.be/_yFPO1ofyF0) if you need it, but basically just wget the .sh and execute it)?

Comment: @Justin try to install via pip (pip install cmake) results in: Requirement already satisfied: cmake in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cmake-3.13.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg (3.13.3)

Comment: @Justin your second option using that video to install worked. Thank you so much!